# what is the best way to draw on HTML

Tags: html, jquery, css, responsive-design, drawing

I am trying to make this design using HTML, CSS , and jQuery.

[image]

I have tried to export the line from the design and put it as an img like the following :

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            
            <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="yellow-circle d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center ">
                    <h1>1</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="w-75 text-center"> 
                <h1 class="text-center">Tell Us How Much Debt You Are Facing</h1>
                <p>Call us or fill out our online form to receive a free, no obligation consultation.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <img class="step-1" src="./Assest/step1.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <img class="line-1" src="./Assest/Vector 6.svg" alt="">
        </div>
```

and the css :

```
.line-1{
    position: absolute;
    left: 560px;
    top:1500px
}
```

but it did not looks like the design , is there any good way to make that like the design exactly?

Comment: Probably canvas, I'm not entirely sure. But you can learn it from here [w3school Canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp). But you can also use SVG and draw it on Illustrator without doing any coding.

Comment: Did you look at the source of the example to see what they did?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear how much of the original you are trying to reproduce, but for the line itself, SVG can be a good option.

Here's what I did by tracing the line with a vector tool in Sketch, then I exported it as a SVG, then I opened that file with a text editor and added it to the HTML

https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/XWNgJKv

You could do the same thing in Illustrator or other graphic design tools.

```
<svg height="517" viewBox="0 0 521 517" width="521" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m519.71875.9296875c-24.996094 14.375-96.300781 64.5976563-161.679687 79.421875-16.68553 3.7833294-50.711459 5.7927067-90.258164 4.2798491-65.61229-2.5099956-148.120463-9.5422982-204.3392194 3.7818232-42.6675685 10.1124233-66.23833205 41.9247342-60.6682421 70.4383282 17.3327833 88.72746 94.5507813 59.976562 123.9804685 65.992187 29.429688 6.015625 97.349086-9.289457 138.398246 56.874251 12.778161 20.596049 9.756603 48.326497-3.666131 82.628183-6.806966 17.395144-16.288831 36.480232-27.74153 57.181818-9.541433 17.246832-21.090378 49.070832-34.646835 95.471998" fill="none" stroke="#2a3287" stroke-dasharray="5" stroke-width="2"/></svg>
```